# Apache Ant FTP connection over TLS

Tags: ant, ftp, ssl

How to connect to FTP over TLS in Apache Ant? Ftp task doesn't seem to support this. Are there some other tasks for FTP over TLS?

Comment: fwiw: the Ant [scp task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) supports sftp file transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTPS has not been widely accepted by the industry. SFTP (part of SSH) is preferred. FTPS suffers the same limitations as FTP and introduces a new one: [Firewall Incompatibilty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS#Firewall_incompatibilities).

This is very likley why the `ftp` task doesn't support it. As Martin Clayton suggests `scp` will do the trick.

Comment: I know about FTPS limitations. At the creation time, using FTPS was only solution for the existing problem.
This issue is obsolete by now.